# Select all rows with multiple conditions in another table

Tags: mysql, join

Here is my simplified database scheme

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `products`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` INT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `properties`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `properties` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` INT NULL,
  `key` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `value` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `products`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (1, 'English Book with AudioCD');
INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (2, 'Polish Book');


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `properties`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO `properties` (`id`, `product_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (1, 1, 'Format', 'Book');
INSERT INTO `properties` (`id`, `product_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (2, 1, 'Format', 'Audio');
INSERT INTO `properties` (`id`, `product_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (3, 2, 'Format', 'Book');
INSERT INTO `properties` (`id`, `product_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (4, 1, 'Language', 'English');
INSERT INTO `properties` (`id`, `product_id`, `key`, `value`) VALUES (5, 2, 'Language', 'Polish');
```

And here are tables representations

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id |           name           |
+----+--------------------------+
|  1 | English Book wit AudioCD |
|  2 | Polish Book              |
+----+--------------------------+

+----+------------+----------+---------+
| id | product_id |   key    |  value  |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
|  1 |          1 | Format   | Book    |
|  2 |          1 | Format   | AudioCD |
|  3 |          2 | Format   | Book    |
|  4 |          1 | Language | English |
|  5 |          2 | Language | Polish  |
+----+------------+----------+---------+
```

I need to select all products that have key 'Format' and value 'Book' and 'AudioCD'. But I need only products that met all of these conditions. So I want only product_id 1, not 2 (beacuse it doesn't have AudioCD). Additionaly I want might to add also Language key to that.

Is there way to do it without multiple JOINS?
The problem with multiple JOINS starts where I would have let's say 20-30 combinations of key-value attributes, because they will be added freely.

Appreciate any hints!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the result by using a combination of a `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` to return the `products` that have both the `Book` and `Audio` values.

```
select p.id, p.name
from products p
inner join properties t
  on p.id = t.product_id
where t.key = 'Format'
  and t.value in ('Book', 'Audio')
group by p.id, p.name
having count(distinct t.value) = 2;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b4b1/8).  Basically, you'll place the values that you want in the `WHERE` clause - this would be the `Book` and `Audio`.  Then you'll `GROUP BY` the `product.id` and `product.name` these are unique to each product. Finally you will use the `HAVING` clause to count the distinct `properties.value` that are returned.  This should equal the number of items that you have in your `WHERE` clause.

This could also be written using conditional aggregation inside of the `HAVING`:

```
select p.id, p.name
from products p
inner join properties t
  on p.id = t.product_id
group by p.id, p.name
having sum(case when t.key = 'Format' and t.value = 'Book' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and sum(case when t.key = 'Format' and t.value = 'Audio' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b4b1/9)

If you want to include the `Language` key, then you can use conditional aggregation in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select p.id, p.name
from products p
inner join properties t
  on p.id = t.product_id
group by p.id, p.name
having 
  sum(case when t.key = 'Format' and t.value = 'Book' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and sum(case when t.key = 'Format' and t.value = 'Audio' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
  and sum(case when t.key = 'Language' and t.value = 'English' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58b4b1/12)

Comment: I would not ever got that! Thanks a lot. I would apply that to my more complex database and check if that works there correctly. But still it's correct answer to above question.

Comment: I didn't mention that (my bad), but what if I want to include language key into this?

Comment: @Piotr What do you mean include the language key?  Do you want to include that in a filter?  If so, what are the requirements? WHERE language = English or what?

Comment: @Piotr I've updated my answer with another example on how to include the `Language` key, I'm guessing since it's not clear the type of filtering you need with that.